# Remote connection with a public IP

Tags: remote-desktop, ip, remote-access

I want to connect remotely to a friend's computer via remote desktop. That remote PC is not in the same network. I should connect through the Internet. I know, we should need a public IP address to do it. I got the friend's router's temporary public IP address. Think that is 100.100.100.100. But the friend's PC's private IP is 192.168.1.2. So there is NAT (Network Address Translation). So couldn't I connect to his computer.

Is there any way like \100.100.100.100\192.168.1.2 to connect to that PC. ?

Comment: you can make things complicated with port forwarding or you can simply use teamviewer.

Comment: Yes. I searched for it. I need to forward the port 3389 and my private ip through my router. Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 6 simple steps:

1. Allow remote connections to the computer you want to access.
2. Make sure Remote Desktop is able to communicate through your firewall.
3. Find the IP address of the computer on your home network that you want to connect to.
4. Open your router's configuration screen and forward TCP port 3389 to the destination computer's IP address.
5. Find your router's public IP address so that Remote Desktop can find it on the Internet.
6. Open Remote Desktop Connection and connect.

Note: you should make sure to allow remote connections to the computer you want to access which is also included in the above [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/allow-remote-desktop-connections-from-outside-your-home-network).

Comment: I see that the port is 3389 for Microsoft RDP, what do I forward for a Pi?